# Get wordpress core jquery to work again after using wp_deregister_script

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I try following code to stop multiple jquery scripts loading onto product category page. This broke a lot of plugins.

```
add_filter('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'change_default_jquery', PHP_INT_MAX);

if (is_product_category() || is_shop()) {
  // product category page or shop
  function change_default_jquery() {
    if (!is_admin() {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', false);   
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to go back and reverse this and used the following code,

```
function getbacke_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'getbacke_scripts');
```

This did not work. How do I get Wordpress to go back to using it's core Jquery site and fix my plugin issue. Every solution I find says to use  `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');` but this has not worked for me. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the filter and its respective function where you have the `wp_deregister_script` is enough. Since wordpress automatically enqueues the jquery script.

If you still have issue make sure you do not have any errors in the browser's console.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got core jquery back with the following code below. However, some plugins are not running but getting jquery back was the number one goal so mission accomplished. Just in case someone needs this run the code once in your themes functions.php file and refresh your page check to see if scripts are loading. In the event they are loading delete this code out of your functions.php file, or else it will continue to load these scripts multiple times. Not the most efficient solution but it works on WP 4.9.4.

```
add_action('wp_print_scripts','add_all_scripts', 100);
function add_all_scripts(){
wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui-core', array( 'jquery' ));
wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui-widget', array( 'jquery' ));
wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui-mouse', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui-accordion', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui-autocomplete', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui-slider', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui-progressbar', array( 'jquery' ));
wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui-tabs', array( 'jquery' ));
wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui-sortable', array( 'jquery' ));
wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui-draggable', array( 'jquery' ));
wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui-droppable', array( 'jquery' ));
wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui-selectable', array( 'jquery' ));
wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui-position', array( 'jquery' ));
wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker', array( 'jquery' ));
wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui-tooltip', array( 'jquery' ));
wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui-resizable', array( 'jquery' ));
wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui-dialog', array( 'jquery' ));
wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui-button', array( 'jquery' ));

//wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );  
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-widget' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-mouse' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-accordion' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-autocomplete' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-slider' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-progressbar' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-tabs' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-sortable' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-draggable' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-droppable' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-selectable' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-position' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-tooltip' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-resizable' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-dialog' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-button' );
}
```